# react-navigation tabBarComponent cannot read property "key" of undefined

Tags: react-navigation

The documentation for react-navigation is pretty unclear to me about how to customise the `tabBarComponent` beyond simply changing colours. I am able to create my custom component for tabs and point to it like so;

```
import { TabNavigator } from 'myComponentsSomewhere'

...

const Navigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Route1: Route1Component,
    Route2: Route2Component,
    ...
  },
  {
    tabBarComponent: props => <TabNavigator {...props} />,
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: colors.first,
      showLabel: false,
    },
  },
)
```

On the `TabNavigator` side, i get a load of props as i would expect;

```
activeTintColor: "#d85089",
getAccessibilityLabel,
getButtonComponent,
...
navigation,
...
```

Within the `navigation` prop, i can get to the `state` and then the routes etc... but i am unable to fire off any of the functions for getting buttons or rendering icons. (`renderIcon`, `getButtonComponent`)

The docs on these functions are weak, but looking at the code, it seems they both require a "route" object that contains a `key`, `routeName` etc.

That shape can be found in the `navigation.state.routes` array - but passing one of those objects simply throws the error;

```
Cannot read property 'key' of undefined
```

Here is an example of that code that errors;

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'

const TabNavigator = props => {
  return props.navigation.state.routes.map(route =>
    props.getButtonComponent(route),
  )
}

export default TabNavigator
```

Ultimately, i want to be able to write my own code to contain the tabs, rather than be restricted to passing code to the react-navigation markup. I don't understand why none of the render functions received in the props will work when passed a complete route object, straight out of the navigation prop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out i was not reading the error properly, which actually told me everything i needed to know...

`Cannot read property 'key' of undefined`

`getButtonComponent` (and all the other getting functions in `navigation` prop) required an object with route included, not just the route.

`getButtonComponent({ route })` rather than `getButtonComponent(route)`

Simplicity wins...